# Laradock error en npm run dev

Tags: laravel, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con Laradock en Laravel versión 5.7

Al intentar hacer un `npm run dev` me arroja el siguiente error

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found
```

lo raro que la carpeta está en node_modules y en algún momento años atrás funcionaba

Busque en internet pero no logré dar  con la respuesta que me funcionara

Les agradecería su ayuda.

Otra pregunta es como hago para bajar la versión de node en laradock, porque voy a el archivo .env y encuentro lo siguiente: `WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION=node`, pero busco esa variable node y no existe

Si lo hago desde la consola dentro del workspace no funciona pareciera como que lo cambia en el momento pero salgo y vuelvo a entrar por más que le haga un down y up sigue teniendo la versión 17 de node

Presiento que muchos errores es debido a la versión de node, ya me ha pasado en otros proyectos que trabajando con la v16 se solucionan varios problemas

Gracias !!!

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el primer error colocando en el package.json del proyecto lo siguiente:

```
"development": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

antes no tenía la primer parte que es la ruta del cross-env, estaba así

"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",

Pero ahora me arroja otro error y creo que es por la versión 17 del node

```
10% building 0/2 entries 2/2 dependencies 0/2 modulesnode:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);

error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

pueden ayudarme con este error ?
Gracias!!!